# Windows installation stuck in boot loop after having installed linux

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, filesystems, reinstall

I am trying to reinstall Windows 10 after having installed debian, changed my HDD to an SSD and eventually installed ubuntu. I have downloaded the ISO and burnt it to an USB stick using rufus on another PC. When I boot the computer up from the stick, the screen encounters some graphical glitches, then stays black for about 20 seconds, and eventually the Windows logo shows up, then the pc reboots immediately and repeats the whole sequence.

I have tried with the most common file systems (FAT32, NTFS, unformatted) and partition tables (GPT, MS-DOS) on both my hard disk and USB stick. The pre-mentioned graphical glitches change depending on the USB stick's filesystem.
I have tried both UEFI and Legacy BIOS. I have also run Memory test and it didn't notice any errors.

My SSD is empty right now.

A little additional informaton (I don't know if it's useful):

1. When I first bought my PC Windows 10 was pre-installed and the hard disk was an HDD (I'm using an SSD right now).
2. A few years ago I tried installing the Debian distribution with non-free firmware bundled, and since then Grub installation has always failed unless I was in legacy BIOS. Thus the UEFI might be damaged, although Windows installation fails on both UEFI and Legacy BIOS.
3. I have tried an used the same installation media on another computer and it works.
4. My system runs both 32-bit and 64-bit, but the Windows version I am trying to install is 64-bit.

Please help me!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try updating the Firmware (BIOS/UEFI) for your computer. Visit the manufacturer website to check for any latest BIOS updates. What version of Windows 10 are you installing? If 2004, did you try an older version like 1903 or 1909?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have installed a 32-bit version of Debian on a 64-bit computer.
In addition, you might have erased the manufacturer's UEFI firmware.

What I would suggest:

- Download and install the manufacturer's UEFI firmware from the manufacturer's website.
  If you need our help, please let us know your computer model.
- Set the BIOS to UEFI
- Install Windows from the installation media.
  If you would like to clean up the disk, during installation specify to format the disk
  (fast format) and install into the Unallocated space.

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems quite possible.
Oddly enough, it looks like the only option to update my UEFI is through a .exe file. Since you've been so kind, do you know if I can use it without Windows somehow?
Otherwise don't worry, Windows 7 recovery disk does work on my laptop, so I can manage to install Windows 7 and run that executable.

Comment: Yes, that would be best if the manufacturer has not provided boot installation media. Although it's possible to create yourself such media, it's not very simple.